# When is the best moment to create a new git branch... before writing new code or after?

Tags: git

Should I create a new branch when I am already in master and I've begun putting some new code in?  Then do I create the new branch and commit on it?

Or do I create a fresh new branch from a clean master and start working on the new code?

I know this is probably simple... but I am only now getting the hang of git and I just want to iron out a few specifics in my workflow.

Comment: "Primarily opinion-based" does not mean unanswerable or unimportant. There is a very clear answer: either way. The question then is who can provide a comparison of the pros and cons of each approach in their answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Should I create a new branch when I am already in master and I've begun putting some new code in? Then do I create the new branch and commit on it?

*Technically*, it doesn't matter when the branch creation and switch occurs - as long as it is before the commit<sup>1</sup>.

None of the working copy changes will be reverted/modified/deleted when creating a new branch off the current ('master') branch and switching to it by-and-by.

> Or do I create a fresh new branch from a clean master and start working on the new code?

Regardless, *I recommend creating the branch before*. It gives clearer focus to the work being done and it becomes a consistent habit that makes it 'harder to forget' and have to tidy up afterwards.

---

<sup>1</sup>Even then it doesn't 'really' matter before the commit is shared as the commits can be tidied up and rebased etc. without affecting anyone else - but it's a bit more awkward in the workflow. I like to think of Git as a mutable-immutable design: commits that *only* you have (ie. have not pushed) are mutable; and every pushed and remotely merged commit should be left well-enough alone.

Comment: I agree with the "create before if possible".  I'll add one other item, though: I think a lot of "becoming good at X" (for many values of X) is learning how to error-correct on the fly, though, as everyone makes mistakes.  This is true of driving a car, baking a cake, writing code, and using your source control system.  Git does let you error-correct, which is a good thing.

Comment: That's a pretty good thing to keep in mind when working with git because it's true and is reality.

Answer (score 1):

> It depends on your projects, you can always either revert or reset the changes by
>   working on your master branch but its not always preferred. Instead the
>   coolest way is to create a brach and work on it.

[Git docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) on branching

> Branching means you diverge from the main line of development and
>   continue to do work without messing with that main line. In many VCS
>   tools, this is a somewhat expensive process, often requiring you to
>   create a new copy of your source code directory, which can take a long
>   time for large projects.

As it is said [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branches-in-a-Nutshell), its not a good practise to also always create numerous branches on large project which is expensive.

```
$ git checkout -b [name_of_your_new_branch]
```

See [here](https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches) for more info. See this [post](https://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2010/06/08/git-d-oh-i-meant-to-create-a-new-branch-first/) on why you should create a branch.